# Dynamically label width with a label background color

Tags: swift, xcode, uilabel

I have a label in my `TableView` Cell and trying to autofit it to the size of the content. It works, but when I add a background color, I see what's wrong here. In my cell, I have a top, left, bottom and right constraint, as you can see in the picture.

How can I adjust the label size to the content?

Edit: I also have this:

```
override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()

    labelChatMessage.sizeToFit()
    labelChatMessage.layoutIfNeeded()

    // Initialization code
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have also tried this UI in one of my project.

Try doing this if it serves your purpose:

- Select the Leading constraint (Left one)
- Select "Show the Size Inspector"
- Change the relation of the constraint to "Greater than or equal"

[image]

- Your constraint and UI in storyboard will look like this:

[image]

- And you will get the UI as :

[image]

I think this is not required in this scenario then:

```
labelChatMessage.sizeToFit()
labelChatMessage.layoutIfNeeded()
```

because I got the output UI without that.